# Problems calling Jsoup in a JSP scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup, scriptlet

I want to show parsed Elements in my JSP page.
I already have Jsoup in my Maven dependencies

I have a class for parsing with jsoup which returns a string.

```
package com.user.jsoup;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupClass {
    public String testMethod() throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.de").get(); 
        String test = doc.title();
        return test;
    }
}
```

My JSP is:

```
<%@page import="com.user.jsoup.JsoupClass"%>


<% 
    JsoupClass jsclass = new JsoupClass();
    out.print(jsclass.testMethod());
%>
```

Unfortunately it won't display anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More details is needed.

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary I have updated my informations.

Comment: It might be possible that document is not loaded properly and before that method is called. Did you debug the application ?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem my adding

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "port");
```

to my JsoupClass